# How do I do a multipart/form file upload with jax-rs?

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

(specifically RESTeasy)

It would be nice (for a single file) to have a method signature like:

```
public void upload(@FormParam("name") ..., @FormParam("file") file: InputStream)
...
```

doable? or am I dreaming? doesn't seem to be that simple.

Comment: Checkout my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73128383/1547266) that is vendor agnostic.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The key is to leverage the @MultipartForm annotations that comes with RESTEasy.  This enables you to define a POJO that contains all the parts of the form and bind it easily.

Take for example the following POJO:

```
public class FileUploadForm {
    private byte[] filedata;

    public FileUploadForm() {}

    public byte[] getFileData() {
        return filedata;
    }

    @FormParam("filedata")
    @PartType("application/octet-stream")
    public void setFileData(final byte[] filedata) {
        this.filedata = filedata;
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is use this POJO in the entity which would look something like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public Response create(@MultipartForm FileUploadForm form) 
{
    // Do something with your filedata here
}
```

Comment: raiglstorfer, how would you setup the request to test this service?

Comment: @c12 I use cURL to test my RESTeasy methods. Something like this should work: `curl -F filedata=@yourfile.png http://localhost:8080/Project/rest-servlet/upload`, more info here: [link](http://curl.haxx.se/)

Comment: What about Resteasy reactive support? https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#multipart

Answer (score 0):

Since [JAX-RS 3.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.1/jakarta-restful-ws-spec-3.1.html#consuming_multipart_formdata) (officially "Jakarta RESTful Web Services"; part of Jakarta EE 10), you can do:

```java
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response postWidget(
        @FormParam("name") String name,
        @FormParam("file") EntityPart file) {
    var fileName = file.getName().orElseThrow();
    var inputStream = file.getContent();
}
```

This is not only a standard, it's also easier to use.

Note that I just found that the `@FormParam` doesn't work here in RestEasy 6.2.7 (I just submitted an [issue](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RESTEASY-3463)). You'll have to read all parts and find your own:

```java
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response postWidget(
        List<EntityPart> parts) {
    var file = parts.stream().filter(part -> "file".equals(part.getName())).findFirst().orElseThrow();
    var inputStream = file.getContent();
}
```