# How do i send a file with jax-rs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, download, jax-rs

How do send a file for download using jax-rs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do a multipart/form file upload with jax-rs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637017/how-do-i-do-a-multipart-form-file-upload-with-jax-rs)

Comment: of course not, this guy want to read a uploaded file, in my case i want to send a file to download

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

public Response getFile(String contentType) {

        File f = new File("/tmp/file.doc");

        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(f);
        response.type(contentType);
        response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file.doc\"");
        return response.build();
    }
```

Comment: @robcast it's not necessary. I submitted an edit to fix.