# Can Resteasy fill in a multipart form?

Tags: javascript, forms, resteasy

I know that I can submit form information from a web page by using the @MultipartForm annotation to bind a POJO to a form. (See [How do I do a multipart/form file upload with jax-rs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637017/how-do-i-do-a-multipart-form-file-upload-with-jax-rs/3280762#3280762)).

What I would like to do, however, is make a Restful call that returns a POJO containing values, and have those values fill in the appropriate form values, which can then be edited and submitted by the user. I know I'd probably need to use JavaScript to first make the rest call, but at that point, is there a way I can use the result to fill in the form?

I could have my rest call return JSON representing the form and use those values to fill in the form with JavaScript, but it would be cool if this could happen automatically, similar to form posting.

Thanks!