# Multipart form upload with GAE (Resteasy)

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

Much like the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301973/multipart-file-upload-on-google-appengine-using-jersey-1-7) is there any way to set JBoss RestEasy not to create temporary file when doing multipart/form-data upload:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public Response create(@MultipartForm FileUploadForm form) 
{
    return Response.status(200).entity(form.toString()).build();
}
```

The main problem with this code is that it runs on top of Google App Engine (GAE) which does not allow to create temporary files, is there any way to solve this issue? The same Apache Jersey code can be set to disable creating tempary files (as provided in the link above)

Is this issue even feasible to fix?

Comment: I found a workaround and posted that here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45765530/1250435